# pywin32 get user of process writing to folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, pywin32

I have been using Tom Goldens great example to monitor a folder with python (http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html). I am using his third example to check for a change and everything works great, but I would really like to also list the process doing the change to the folder. I have tried searching for a solution, but havent found anything useful yet, can anybody help?

My first idea was to look for something in win32con, which Tim uses in the CreateFile, but I can't find anything useful.. :-/

```
    ACTIONS = {
    1: "Created",
    2: "Deleted",
    3: "Updated",
    4: "Renamed from something",
    5: "Renamed to something"
}

FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001

try:
    # Setup "listener", that looks for changes on the path 
    hDir = win32file.CreateFile(
        my_path,
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
        win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        None,
        win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
        win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
        None
    )
except:
     sys.exit()

while 1:
        results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW(
            hDir,
            2048,
            True,
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE |
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
            None,
            None
        )
        for action, file in results:


#This is where I do my action
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible using regular win32 API. A filesystem minifilter driver would be able to get the process that initiated the I/O request, but you would have to write that in C or C++ and it's not trivial. Why do you need that information? It sounds a bit like an XY problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will look in to that, to see if I can do something useful in that direction. Well, it is a minor project for a small surveillance system, that I am working with. Python was the first language of choice, so I was hoping to find a solution with that.